# Error using Makefile to generate TeX file

Tags: xetex, makefile

I'm trying to create a `Makefile` that generates my document.

```
➜  resume git:(main) ✗ cat Makefile 
.PHONY: .

CC = xelatex
CURRENT_DIR = .
RESUME_DIR = ./src
RESUME_SRCS = $(shell find $(RESUME_DIR) -name '*.tex')

resume: $(CURRENT_DIR)/resume.tex $(RESUME_SRCS)
        $(CC) -output-directory=$(CURRENT_DIR) $<

clean:
        rm -rf $(CURRENT_DIR)/*.pdf
```

However, I keep getting the following error, despite the PDF has been successfully generated:

```
(./src/education.tex) (./src/extracurricular.tex) [2] (./resume.aux) )
Output written on ./resume.pdf (2 pages).
Transcript written on ./resume.log.
make: *** [Makefile:9: resume] Error 1
```

Is there something wrong with the `Makefile`? I have been searching around and can't find the reasons.

Comment: it made the pdf so I assume the makefile is Ok but tex returned a non zero return status (eg if you scrolled past an error)

Comment: The usual thing is to run use `latexmk`, which is TeX's version of Make.  But there are situations where that won't work, and Make might be able to do it.  Even then, you might have better luck with `CC = latexmk`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you're missing something in your transcript. Looking at the makefile that you provide and your snippet of code, I'm guessing that what's happening is that you're trying to run xelatex on files in your src directory that aren't top-level LaTeX files which is why you're getting the error. To be honest, I don't know that make is a tool that makes sense for LaTeX—unlike with say C where you're going to compile multiple `.c` files into `.o` file and then link those into the final executable, the production of the output of LaTeX is a direct compilation of a single top level file (possibly running multiple times). That said, if you're really wanting to try to use a makefile for your purposes, I would replace the definition of `RESUME_SRCS` with:

```
RESUME_SRCS = ./src/resume.tex
```

and you should get the desired result.

**When Make makes sense in a LaTeX flow**

The situation where it could make sense to use a tool like Make is when you have programmatically-generated files that form input into a LaTeX document. For example, you might have some pre-processing to generate illustrations. Then, in that instance, the makefile would be able to only regenerate illustrations if the underlying data files change and then run LaTeX.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work either. I guess you are right that using `make` for latex is kinda not the right tool.

Comment: @QuangThinhHa You might find the following useful as a model: https://gist.github.com/TakashiUNUMA/7002805 I also suspect that there might be some errors in your resume.tex file